# Como pegar informações do Header em requisição Post, Ionic 3

Tags: angular, ionic, ionic3, jwt, token

Olá, eu preciso pegar o Token que retorna no Header depois que executo um POST, gostaria de saber uma maneira de conseguir isto, estou usando Ionic 3 com Angular. Qual a melhor maneira de pegar o campo Authorization que a Api me retorna direto do header?

Meu código

```
ionViewDidLoad(){
   this.loginProvider.getToken(this.data, this.headers).subscribe(
     data=>{
        console.log(data); //Aqui eu preciso pegar o header não o body
     }, error=>{
        console.log(error);
     }
   );
```

Ele retorna null pq a requisição não retorna nada mesmo, só o token no header. Não sei se esse comportamento tá correto.

Comment: voce q tem controle do backend?

Comment: @rafaelphp Sim, tenho

Comment: Entao retorne o token no body e nao no headers assim voce pode pegar o token e salvar no sua front-end e depois envia o token para url que precisa .headers("Authorization Baer token")

Comment: voce tmb pode criar uma intercept e adicionar a sua app, assim voce pode tratar melhor os dados de requisicoes

Comment: @rafaelphp eu solicitei ao arquiteto responsável pela API que retornássemos o token no body, acontece que eu preciso implementar isso ainda hj, e é uma atualização que não iremos poder fazer por agora. Tem alguma forma de fazer isso pelo header mesmo?

Comment: criar uma classe intercept veja esse video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vHoNOpfDdNQ

Comment: mas provavelmente ele tenha que criar via body, pois nunca usei nenhuma api que no header e sempre via body, pede pra ele ver sobre JWT https://jwt.io/introduction/

Answer (score 1):

Crie uma classe `InterceptService` para interceptar as requisicoes http,

```
// Angular
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpEvent, HttpInterceptor, HttpHandler, HttpRequest, 
HttpResponse } from '@angular/common/http';
// RxJS
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { tap } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { debug } from 'util';
import {ToastrService} from 'ngx-toastr';
import {LoadingService} from '../../../../views/pages/_services/loading.service';

@Injectable()
export class InterceptService implements HttpInterceptor {

constructor(private toast: ToastrService,private loadingService: LoadingService){}

// intercept request and add token
intercept(
    request: HttpRequest<any>,
    next: HttpHandler
): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    // tslint:disable-next-line:no-debugger
    // modify request
    // request = request.clone({
    //  setHeaders: {
    //      Authorization: `Bearer ${localStorage.getItem('accessToken')}`
    //  }
    // });
    // console.log('----request----');
    // console.log(request);
    // console.log('--- end of request---');

    return next.handle(request).pipe(
        tap(
            event => {
                 if (event instanceof HttpResponse) {
                    // console.log('all looks good');
                    // http response status code
                    // console.log(event.status);
                }
            },
            error => {

                this.toast.error(error.message,error.status);
                this.loadingService.waitLoadingClose();
                // http response status code
                // console.log('----response----');
                // console.error('status code:');
                // tslint:disable-next-line:no-debugger
                //console.error(error.status);
                //console.error(error.message);
                // console.log('--- end of response---');
            }
        )
    );
}
}
```

adicione a linha abaixo no seu Modulo:

```
providers: [
    InterceptService,
    {
        provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
        useClass: InterceptService,
        multi: true
    },
],
```

na propria classe `InterceptService` voce pode pegar os `headers`